# PIL canot open/save Images correctly, Broken encoding/compression

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do some basic Images Manipulation with PIL but my problem is that PIL doesn't load the `Image` correctly. So when I do:

```
import os

from PIL import Image


INPUTFOLDER="data/"
OUTPUTFOLDER="data/resize/"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in os.listdir(INPUTFOLDER):

        img = Image.open(open(INPUTFOLDER+filename, 'rb'))        
        out = file(OUTPUTFOLDER + os.path.splitext(filename)[0]+ "-2.jpeg", "w")
        img.save(out)
```

the saved image is broke due to compression failures.

I am using Win7, Python2.7 and PIL 1.1.7.

Example of a corrupted image:

[image: here]

Comment: Are you sure that it's a compression bug?

Comment: Could you post the uncorrupted image so that we may try to replicate your results? And a **complete** program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You can always user Pillow: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow

Comment: @swietyy already tried, didnt helped.

Comment: @Rob this is more or less the completed programm now, i stripped everything else to make sure the problems don't come from the manipulation...but i will add the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unistall PIL and install from a fresh download!  The other issue *may* be that you are not opening your output file in **binary** mode:

```
out = file(OUTPUTFOLDER + os.path.splitext(filename)[0]+ "-2.jpeg", "wb")
```

Comment: Why should that help?

Comment: Because if your PIL installation is broken it will fix it!  If a given version of PIL was unable to save as jpeg then we would have been hearing a lot about it so it is the PIL on __your__ machine.

Comment: It was the Issue that i didnt opened the output file in binary mode. Thanks for the help, totally overlooked it.